# using different shell with GNU Make recursively: why substituting a different /bin/sh as root does not seem to work?

Tags: makefile

I want to temporarily use a different shell than default `/bin/sh` with recursive GNU Make setup.  Because of recursivity, I can't use the SHELL hack, or I would have to (is that right?) edit all the many makefiles (on each command line I would have to do

```
$(MAKE) SHELL=$(SHELL)
```

), which I don't want to do.

Since this is just temporary, I thought I would become root, back up `/bin/sh` and edit it to something what I want:

```
#!/bin/dash
echo dash shell
/bin/dash $@
```

It follows from the GNU Make manual that it runs the recipe lines with

`execve("/bin/sh", "-c <recipe line>")`

then based on the documentation of `execve` this should work.   But it does not.  When I run GNU Make, it completely ignores the above changed `/bin/sh` and works as if it was not changed.

Why and how to get this to work?

Comment: As you wrote: _Since GNU Make runs the recipe lines with..._ So, as you have 3 lines, GNU make will run the 3 lines, one after the other, with `execve`. The will be 3 invocations of `execve`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I disagree with you, but it does not matter, that was not my question. I just want to see "dash shell" I don't - I see nothing, only the normal Make output, as if `/bin/sh` was not changed.

Comment: Strange, I just tried and I see `dash shell`. Are you really using these 3 lines as the recipe of a make rule? And why do you disagree with the line per line execution? Did you try?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet of course I tried the whole thing before asking - as for `execve`, again, I think you are seeing a recipe in there with 3 lines, this is not a recipe

Comment: Oh, I got it. Sorry, I've seen `$@` and too rapidly concluded that it was the make automatic variable. Could it be that make does not use `/bin/sh`? Is it what is printed if you `echo $(SHELL)` in a makefile?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thank you - yes that would be my guess to, but unfortunately, the manual clearly says that it uses `/bin/sh` by default

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, this is just a hypothesis, supported by some evidence other than above.  When the internal `SHELL` make variable is default, that is `/bin/sh`, the login shell, then GNU Make does not run recipes with

```
execve("/bin/sh", "-c recipe")
```

but instead, just uses

```
execve("recipe")
```

This would clearly contradict the following line from the GNU Make manual

"the program /bin/sh is used as the shell. The argument(s) passed to the shell are taken from the variable .SHELLFLAGS. The default value of .SHELLFLAGS is -c normally"